# How to actually type CTRL-A in a linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnu-screen

How do I to invoke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> in a Linux terminal session. I am trying to share a screen using screen.

The command to turn on multiuser is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> :multiuser on , I know how to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> on my keyboard but what is the command line version of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>?

How would I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> :multiuser on, without Linux telling that the command is not found?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're in a `screen` session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>A</kbd> again.

Answer (score 1):

I knew you could send commands from within a screen session to the screen.
So from the man page:

```
  -X   Send the specified command to a running screen  session.  You  can
        use  the  -d or -r option to tell screen to look only for attached
        or detached screen sessions. Note that this command  doesn't  work
        if the session is password protected.
```

this leads to:

```
screen -X multiuser on
```

Invoking this from within your screen should do the job. Could not test it myself right now.